# custom notification sound is not playing windows universal app 8.1

Tags: audio, notifications, win-universal-app

i want to play custom sound when notification received but instead of custom sound default sound is playing. whta wrong is going on here. even the audio on correct path.

```
 public void AddNotification(int t, String date,String idPrefix)
{
    ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;
    XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

    DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now;
    string period = String.Empty;

    switch (t)
    {
        case 0:
            period = "15min";
            dueTime = GetNotificationTime(date, dueTime, 15);
            break;
        case 1:
            period = "30min";
            dueTime = GetNotificationTime(date, dueTime, 30);
            break;
        case 2:
            period = "1hr";
            dueTime = GetNotificationTime(date, dueTime, 60);
            break;
        default: break;
    }

    XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("show time"));
    toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Watch show in " + period));

    //XmlNodeList toastImageAttributes = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");

    //((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///assets/CameraSelected.png");
    //((XmlElement)toastImageAttributes[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "Camera Selected");

    IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
    ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("launch", "LandingPage.xaml");

    XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
    audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/Guitar.aifc");
     toastNode.AppendChild(audio);
    //launch tost immediatly

    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);

}
```

What wrong i am doing here. can anyone guide me in implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution

It won't support aifc files. i have converted sound file to wav  and now it is working fine